# max if functions in Excel to return text from a different row matching the max if conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2016

I have an Excel spreadsheet with a summary table that contains credit card charges information from different sheets. The sheets have columns A to F with 'Date', 'Cardholder Name', 'Amount', 'Result (Approved, Declined, Error)', 'Card Type', and 'Card Ending'.

I used a formula to find the last 'Approved' date by the summary of the 'Cardholder Name' using the following formula:

```
{=MAX(IF(A2&"Approved"='All Charges'!$B$2:$B$5000&'All Charges'!$D$2:$D$5000,'All Charges'!$B$2:$A$5000,0))}
```

Now I want to add another column to the summary table. This column should return the last 'Card Ending' for each 'Cardholder Name', even if it was not approved, based on the last date recorded on the spreadsheet for each 'Cardholder Name'.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. What have you tried so far? Also, please add an image to your question showing anonymized data. Thx